# how to write a public void delete method in 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, alphanumeric, alphabetical

I have a 2D array which contains the strings as letters starting from **A goes to row 0** and from B goes to row 1 and etc..we can use ***charAt*** method and **ASCII value for A is 65** and ***B is 66*** and so on. Its a method that **takes an argument a String** and **deletes the parameter** from the corresponding row and also deletes the entire row of the Structure. The only thing wrong IN THE FOLLOWING CODE is the remove method.

```
public AlphaList() {
    this.list=new String[26][];
    for (int row=0; row<this.list.length; row++) {
        list[row]=new String[0];
    }
}

public void insert(String value) {
    int firstChar=(int) value.charAt(0)-65;
    String[] newList=new String[list[firstChar].length+1];
    newList[newList.length-1]=value;
    for(int i=0; i<list[firstChar].length;i++){
        newList[i]=list[firstChar][i];
    }
    list[firstChar]=newList;}


public void remove(String value) {
    int firstChar=(int) value.charAt(0)-65;
    String[] newList=new String[list[firstChar].length-1];
    newList[newList.length-1]=value;
    for(int i=0; i<list[firstChar-1].length;i++){
        newList[i]=list[firstChar-1][i];
    }
    list[firstChar]=newList;
}
```

Comment: What should your delete method do? Remove a given string from the array? What does it do?  Add some output so you can see what happens.

Comment: it just deletes the passed string from the array list and so reduces the row by one.

Comment: And did you observe, what it really does? Print out your lists, and you'll see.

Comment: Is a `List<List<String>>` permitted?

Comment: NOPE.. THERE IS NO ELEMENTS IN THE LISTS TO PRINTOUT..

Comment: If there are no elements, what should the remove method then do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code of the function you delete the last two elements and save the function argument on the last cell.
You need to write a function that find the index of the stored parameter (if it exist) and the use this code to delete it from array:

```
public void remove(String value) {
    int firstChar=(int) value.charAt(0)-65;
    int index = FindIndex(list[firstChar],value); // Function that return the index of value
    String[] newList=new String[list[firstChar].length-1];

    for(int i=0; i<index ;i++)
        newList[i]=list[firstChar-1][i];

    for(int i=index; i<list[firstChar-1].length;i++)
        newList[i]=list[firstChar-1][i+1];

    list[firstChar]=newList;
}
```